# Datetime of dataframe column switching from pandas to numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have an iterative function that is constantly pulling data from a website into a dataframe (using BeautifulSoup), then saving to a CSV. This includes a datetime column, 'Timestamp'.

Occasionally when reloading the dataframe, the 'type' of my datetime column changes from pandas to numpy, however I can't catch where this would happen. I'd like to force my program to always make the datetime column of pandas type.

I've tried printing out the 'type' along multiple points in the program. The type only seems to change between runs, not during.

I also can't replicate when this happens. I could maybe reiterate the program 5-10 times before it does it.

All writes are done as such:

```
l = []
d = {}
...
d["Timestamp"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(
                float(item.find("span", {"class": "time_date_info"})['data-timestamp']))
l.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
...
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

All reads are coded as:

```
pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=['Timestamp'], index_col=0)
```

...

I get no errors, but if I run:

```
print(df['Timestamp'][0])
print(type(df['Timestamp'][0]))
```

To start with, I get the result I want which is as follows:

```
2019-06-22 17:53:54
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Then from a certain point, get results like:

```
2019-06-24T11:36:35.000000000
<class 'numpy.datetime64'>
```

I'm wanting to always have the pandas timestamp type.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Do you mind to have a look at this doc [mcve](/help/mcve) and write a question accordingly?

Comment: Apologies, I tried my best to follow as such. Unfortunately I can't write reproducible code more so than I've done, as I can't actually reproduce the fault consistently!

Comment: Apparently, it seems to be a problem derived from how you scrape the data. Without relevant information, you hardly are going to receive help.

Comment: I think it's more how I'm reading it to a dataframe, maybe I need a custom parse function?

If I don't parse as I read, I get the correct str, however if I do parse I get numpy/pandas times interchangeably. Is there a way to force the parse to always give pandas type?